# Div - 200% width, without X scrollbar

Tags: css, rotation, scrollbar, overflow

i have a problem with CSS3, i need make a background with a specific shape. I used a CSS3 transform to rotate rectangle. But i need bigger rectangle than resolution of display and center it from left side of wrap div ("letter"). How can i hide X-line scrollbar? Or is there another way how solve this problem? (Yes i can use image for background, this is easy, but im trying use CSS3.) Thank you guys and sorry for my bad English.

This is example:

```
.letter {
   position: relative;
   width: 1000px;
   margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.letter .shape {
    position: absolute;
    width: 2000px;
    height: 300px;
    left: -500px;
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
    background: rgb(25,171,255);
}
```

Comment: you can use overflow hidden in body , body{overflow: hidden;}.